# Python: Using Elasticsearch Scan to get more than 10,000 results ScanError

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to query Elasticsearch and print all results for the query. The default max is 10,000, but I'd like to expand this max to much larger. I'm working with Python.

I'm using Elasticsearch.helpers.scan. It seems to work, but then during the middle of printing the results I get this error:

```
elasticsearch.helpers.ScanError: Scroll request has only succeeded on 66 shards out of 80.
```

I'm not sure what this means at all, could someone please explain and provide a solution to fix this?

Also, if theres a better/easier module/api to use other than Elasticsearch.helpers.scan, please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post any relevant exceptions from the Elasticsearch logs when this occurs?

Answer (score 6):

Pass raise_on_error=False to the scan function.

```
res = scan(es, query=query, scroll='50m', size=1000, raise_on_error=False)
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: While helpful for certain best-effort queries, this is not a universal "fix." This will silently drop entire shards' worth of documents and ruins the integrity of your result set; documents that match your query may exist but will not be returned. Be careful with this workaround.

Answer (score 2):

What might indeed help to find out more information about the exception reason is quite simple - just turn on `DEBUG` log for Elasticsearch python modules you're using:

```
import logging
from elasticsearch import logger as elasticsearch_logger
elasticsearch_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

and consequently check the logs around your `scan()` call.